# How do I make Piglins dance in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

So, I'm trying to get piglins to dance in Bedrock Edition, but they don't seem to dance when I play Pigstep.

How do I get piglins to dance on Minecraft Bedrock Edition? Do I need to use `/function`?

Comment: What makes you think that piglins can dance? Have you considered the possibility that piglins *can't* dance at all?

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 When they kill Hoglin they dance, see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=udUpqflctSk&t=278s

Answer (score 9):

Piglins CAN dance, but you can't make them dance. To make Piglins dance this has to happen:

1. There must be more than one Piglin and more than one Hoglin
2. They can't be in a Bastion Remnant.
3. There is a 15% (Not completely sure) chance Piglins will hunt Hoglins
4. After successfully hunting the Hoglins there's a 10% chance of them doing a victory dance.

BTW when they do dance they dance for about 5 seconds.

Answer (score 3):

Piglins don't dance via jukeboxes. The only way for piglins to actually dance is them having a victory hunting down hoglins.

Here's a screenshot where I spotted such happening:

[image: Victory Piglin Dance]

I happened to see them killing a hoglin there while exploring the nether and pictured their victory.

Answer (score -4):

Yes, piglins can dance. In the original Minecraft, they don't, but if you download a dancing piglin spawn egg in minecraft PE, they do.

Comment: How do you "download a dancing piglin spawn egg"